# Any Working code for cross platform message catalog without having to duplicate the message strings?

Tags: c++, localization, cross-platform, catalog, string-table

On linux, gencat works beautifully with .msg file with gencat, catopen, catgets and catclose
On Windows, mc or rc file's stringtable works beautifully with LoadString.

Just wondering if there is any working implementation of gencat on windows. I googled and found many copies from freebsd or apple implementation but it misses on equivalent catopen implementation or its its little old.

I dont want to use MingGW or Cigwin implementation in my project.

Please suggest if you know of any working cross platform implementations for message catalogs  which helps to not duplicate the strings in 2 different formats.

Comment: I'd say go with gettext but I totally don't understand the very last sentence, so I might miss the point completely...

Comment: Thanks pawel for the reply. I agree that GNU gettext was one option and i read somewhere that we have gettext implementation on win32 as well. 2 issues with this: 1. As I understand (told) that its a GNU license and some folks here are not comfortable here with that. 2, My last sentence means that if we go to gettext's PO/MO files then we have 2 sources of same messages, one in mc for windows and 2nd in PO.            Hence this is what I did, I am using mc file windows and using a script to convert mc to msg so that I can use open group's gencat to create cat file and using it on linux. Thks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [gettext](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm) contains an implementation of the old [catgets](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/catgets.html) interface (as well as it's own newer and better interface you might want to consider).

Answer (score 0):

Will the Resource Management features in the ICU project http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/resources suffice?